# weka.core.UnassignedClassException: Class index is negative (not set)!

Tags: java, weka

I try to implement linear regression over an csv file. Here is the content of the csv file:

> X1;X2;X3;X4;X5;X6;X7;X8;Y1;Y2;
>
> 0.98;514.50;294.00;110.25;7.00;2;0.00;0;15.55;21.33;
> 0.98;514.50;294.00;110.25;7.00;3;0.00;0;15.55;21.33;
> 0.98;514.50;294.00;110.25;7.00;4;0.00;0;15.55;21.33;
> 0.98;514.50;294.00;110.25;7.00;5;0.00;0;15.55;21.33;
> 0.90;563.50;318.50;122.50;7.00;2;0.00;0;20.84;28.28;
> 0.90;563.50;318.50;122.50;7.00;3;0.00;0;21.46;25.38;
> 0.90;563.50;318.50;122.50;7.00;4;0.00;0;20.71;25.16;
> 0.90;563.50;318.50;122.50;7.00;5;0.00;0;19.68;29.60;
> 0.86;588.00;294.00;147.00;7.00;2;0.00;0;19.50;27.30;
> 0.86;588.00;294.00;147.00;7.00;3;0.00;0;19.95;21.97;
> 0.86;588.00;294.00;147.00;7.00;4;0.00;0;19.34;23.49;
> 0.86;588.00;294.00;147.00;7.00;5;0.00;0;18.31;27.87;
> 0.82;612.50;318.50;147.00;7.00;2;0.00;0;17.05;23.77;
>
> ...
>
> 0.71;710.50;269.50;220.50;3.50;2;0.40;5;12.43;15.59;
> 0.71;710.50;269.50;220.50;3.50;3;0.40;5;12.63;14.58;
> 0.71;710.50;269.50;220.50;3.50;4;0.40;5;12.76;15.33;
> 0.71;710.50;269.50;220.50;3.50;5;0.40;5;12.42;15.31;
> 0.69;735.00;294.00;220.50;3.50;2;0.40;5;14.12;16.63;
> 0.69;735.00;294.00;220.50;3.50;3;0.40;5;14.28;15.87;
> 0.69;735.00;294.00;220.50;3.50;4;0.40;5;14.37;16.54;
> 0.69;735.00;294.00;220.50;3.50;5;0.40;5;14.21;16.74;
> 0.66;759.50;318.50;220.50;3.50;2;0.40;5;14.96;17.64;
> 0.66;759.50;318.50;220.50;3.50;3;0.40;5;14.92;17.79;
> 0.66;759.50;318.50;220.50;3.50;4;0.40;5;14.92;17.55;
> 0.66;759.50;318.50;220.50;3.50;5;0.40;5;15.16;18.06;
> 0.64;784.00;343.00;220.50;3.50;2;0.40;5;17.69;20.82;
> 0.64;784.00;343.00;220.50;3.50;3;0.40;5;18.19;20.21;
> 0.64;784.00;343.00;220.50;3.50;4;0.40;5;18.16;20.71;
> 0.64;784.00;343.00;220.50;3.50;5;0.40;5;17.88;21.40;
> 0.62;808.50;367.50;220.50;3.50;2;0.40;5;16.54;16.88;
> 0.62;808.50;367.50;220.50;3.50;3;0.40;5;16.44;17.11;
> 0.62;808.50;367.50;220.50;3.50;4;0.40;5;16.48;16.61;
> 0.62;808.50;367.50;220.50;3.50;5;0.40;5;16.64;16.03;

I read this csv file and implement linear regression implementation. Here is the source code in java:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
     {

          
         String csvFile = null;       
         CSVLoader loader = null;         
         Remove remove =null;        
         Instances data =null;        
         LinearRegression model = null;
         int numberofFeatures = 0;
         
         try 
         {
        
             csvFile = "C:\\Users\\Taha\\Desktop/ENB2012_data.csv";         
             loader = new CSVLoader();
          
         
             // load CSV      
             loader.setSource(new File(csvFile));   
             data = loader.getDataSet();
             //System.out.println(data);
             numberofFeatures = data.numAttributes();
             
             System.out.println("number of features: " + numberofFeatures);
                     
             data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes() - 2);
         
             //remove last attribute Y2
             remove = new Remove();         
             remove.setOptions(new String[]{"-R", data.numAttributes()+""});
             remove.setInputFormat(data);  
             
             data = Filter.useFilter(data, remove);
            
            // data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes() - 2);
             
             model = new LinearRegression();
             model.buildClassifier(data); 
             System.out.println(model);
             
         } catch (Exception e) { 
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
         }
```

I am getting an error, *weka.core.UnassignedClassException: Class index is negative (not set)!* at the line *model.buildClassifier(data);* Number of features is 1, however, it is expected to be 9.They are *X1;X2;X3;X4;X5;X6;X7;X8;Y1;Y2* What am I missing?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: code seems ok. Maybe there is an issue with csv file. I would suggest to use commas between values or try to convert csv to arff.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add after the line `data=loader.getDataSet()`, the next lines which will resolve your  exception:

```
if (data.classIndex() == -1) {
        System.out.println("reset index...");
        instances.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes() - 1);
    }
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, it seems like a little bug in source code, my weka version is 3.8.2

Answer (score 0):

Since I can not find any solution to that problem, I decided to position data into Oracle database and I read data from Oracle. There is an import utility in Oracle  Sql Developer and I used it. That solves my problem. I write this article for people who has the same problem. 
Here is the detailed information about connecting an Oracle database for weka.

http://tahasozgen.blogspot.com.tr/2016/10/connection-to-oracle-database-in-weka.html